# TypeScript target ES3

Tags: typescript, tsc

`Array.prototype.indexOf` and `Date.now` have been introduced in ES5. Why doesn't Typescript transpile, if I compile following code stored in file test.ts?

```
Date.now();
[1,2,3].indexOf(2);
```

The command I use is `tsc -t es3 test.ts`. The resulting test.js is completely identical to test.ts.

Comment: [TypeScript doesn't polyfill](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6468#issuecomment-171400551) like Babel does.

Comment: babel doesn't polyfill. Babel *uses* a polyfill (essentially core-js), which you can use with TypeScript as well 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn't Typescript transpile, if I compile following code stored in file test.ts?

- TypeScript doesn't polyfill.
- Use corejs to polyfill

## More

- Lib option : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#polyfill-for-old-javascript-engines