# Why does an ES3 target not result in the replacement of map or filter?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a TypeScript project that will be executed by an ES3 runtime. Naturally it would be nice to use `Array.map`, `Array.filter`, etc.

I set the target to `ES3` and saw that TypeScript transpiles classes into functions - which makes sense. However, `Array.map`, `Array.filter`, etc, are untouched.

Do these have to be polyfilled manually? If so, what's the reasoning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript target ES3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823338/typescript-target-es3)

Comment: I see `babel/preset-typescript`. Is there any solid examples on how to wire this into a TS app without webpack?

Comment: Like the linked answer describes, you probably need to use polyfills (like corejs).